# Understanding php loop behaviors

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

I have a foreach loop and want to list out all the items in an array. The behavior is straightforward, and works like this:

```
 $posttags = get_the_tags();
        if ($posttags) {
          foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $tagnames = $tag->name . ', ' ;
            echo $tagnames; 
        }
    }
```

this code posts the following string: adenosine, blood pressure, Caffeine, cocaine, heart, neurotransmitters, spiders, web

which is every tag name in the array.

However, I would like to use this string outside of the foreach loop, however whenever I do `echo $tagnames;` outside of thee foreach loop, like this:

```
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
        if ($posttags) {
          foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $tagnames = $tag->name . ', ' ; 
        }
      }    

echo $tagnames;
```

then only the last tag which is web is echo'd. Why is this? and how can I use the full string outside of the foreach loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have to do is initialise an empty variable out of the loop and then concatenate the tags using the `.=` syntax.

```
$tagnames = '';
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
    foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $tagnames .= $tag->name . ', ' ; 
    }
}    

echo $tagnames;
```

Comment: Wow, this works!!! Thank you so much. I have two questions. why does the variable need to be created outside of the loop (I tried it without the first `$tagnames = '';` and it works fine)? and what does the period before the = do in `$tagnames .= $tag->name . ', ' ;` does it still function as concatenation?

Comment: php allow you even to concatenate the strings even if you are using a variable not initialised. Btw in this case you needed because otherwise when you do the `echo $tagnames`, `$tagnames` could not exist if `$posttags` is empty. The `.=` is used to concatenate a string to an original one. So if you have $a = 'a'; $a .= 'b'; is equal to $a = $a . 'b';

Comment: ...to add to ^ @ChrisHaugen by not concatenating, you are overwriting your variables on each iteration.

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't know you could concatenate like this. You're rly smart! and thank you Fred, I'm glad stack is here for when I can't grasp a concept myself!

Comment: if you want to get sexy create a new array and use implode - eliminates trailing comma. http://codepad.viper-7.com/UvEHoQ

Comment: @Dagon would it be `echo implode( ', ',  $tag->name );`